# How to extend Visual Studio to provide override-like behavior?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vsx, extensibility

When you type the `override` keyword in a C# file in VS and press Space, you get a second menu offering the method to override. Can I extend this behavior with my own custom code that would use another keyword to pop up my own list of actions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to augment the list with more keywords or to even create your own list entirely.  The interface you are looking for in Visual Studio 2010 is `ICompletionSource`.  This isn't a simple interface though and it's hard to give a full sample in a stackoverflow answer but there are plenty of samples online to take a look at.

I think the best place to start is the editor samples available on codeplex

- http://editorsamples.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

What other keyword do you want to use? If it's C#, pressing ctrl+space will open the auto-complete/intellisense menu.

If this is for writing another language using Visual Studio, perhaps this [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/VSIPMarketing/VSX212-Adding-a-Language-Service-into-Visual-Studio-2010/) is of use.

Here's the [extending Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff677564.aspx) start page, in case it's helpful.